# Transformer library that comes with Java converts spaces in file paths to %20

Tags: java, xml, urlencode, filepath

Here is a test application that writes out XML Files.

Why are the spaces in my path being converted to `%20`?

```
public class XmlTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String filename = "C:\\New Folder\\test.xml";
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

            File xmlFile = new File(filename);
            if (xmlFile.exists())
            {
                xmlFile.delete();
            }
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(xmlFile);
            transformer.transform(source, result);

        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (TransformerException tfe)
        {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\New%20Folder\test.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:70)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:287)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:330)
    at avm.trans.xml.XmlTest.main(XmlTest.java:52)
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Script? If it is Java then it is not a script. You should export your application and run it outside of an IDE.

Comment: Java programs aren't usually termed "scripts", so I'm curious about what this actually is. Is it just an ordinary application, that happens to be small and single-purpose?

Comment: Yes, it's a java application that I pass around as a `.java` file and we just run them through our IDE's. Whether it "should" be run outside of an IDE I believe would be another issue.

Comment: OK, we're going to have to see some of your code.

Comment: The first step is to find out the exact location where the "crash" occurs. If there is an `Exception`, there should be a stack-trace.

Comment: The issue does not appear to be IDE related, but instead library related. I have edited the question to present the correct information.

Comment: I suppose the question should state that the paths are being url-encoded, as other special characters like `?` are also being converted to the appropriate hex code. However, I'm inclined to believe it is one of the settings that I have used in one of the lines that is causing the library to believe that I am working with URL's and not file paths.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to change this line:

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(xmlFile);
```

into this:

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(xmlFile));
```

I have no Idea, why the filename is handled as an URL.

Comment: Strange, in my inbox was a completely different comment, than this.

Comment: I moved it out into an answer.

Comment: I still think, that this behavior looks like a bug.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach this works flawlessly! thanks! In my case, there was no issue on tomcat, but jboss was unable to find the xml file.

Answer (score 3):

Following from @ChristianKuetbach's answer, it would seem like the argument passed to the `StreamResult` constructor determines how it will be handled.

From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html#StreamResult%28java.lang.String%29)

```
public StreamResult(String systemId)  
    Construct a StreamResult from a URL.  
Parameters:  
    systemId - Must be a String that conforms to the URI syntax.

public StreamResult(File f)
   Construct a StreamResult from a File.
Parameters:
   f - Must a non-null File reference.
```

So initially, I was passing a `String` path, and so presumably the `StreamResult` decided to take the initiative to encode it automatically, rather than assuming it is "a String that comforms to the URI syntax".

As a result, passing in a `File` object told it to handle it as a file path instead of a URL and therefore spaces (and other special characters) were not encoded.

Answer (score 2):

This problem might also occur in cases of paths containing **special characters**, for which the first answer isn't helping pretty much(with the conversion, that is). 
For example, in my case the path of my file contained the char "`" that was automatically translated into "%60".

I solved my problem by changing the code line:

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(xmlFile);
```

> result = D:/Work/.../%60Projects/.../xmlFile.xml

into code lines:

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(xmlFile);
result.setSystemId(URLDecoder.decode(xmlFile.toURI().toURL().toString(), "UTF-8"));
```

> result = D:/Work/.../`Projects/.../xmlFile.xml

This overrides the URL encoding problem that's implemented by default within the StreamResult class.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This was exactly my problem. Pure GENIUS!! Thank you for sharing! Editing to add the exceptions that you have to handle.