# Android rewriting to file creates new one

Tags: java, android, xml, file

I have a piece of code that creates a xml file:

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "android/data/com.travip");
directory.mkdirs();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);
xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "trip");
xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "name", name);
xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "description", description);
xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "startdate", startdate);
xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "enddate", enddate);
xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "trip");
xmlSerializer.endDocument();
xmlSerializer.flush();
String dataWrite = writer.toString();
fos.write(dataWrite.getBytes());
fos.close();

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor prefseditor;
sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefseditor = sharedpreferences.edit();
prefseditor.putString("activeTrip", name);
prefseditor.apply();
```

This give me a files in the form of "name of the trip.trp". After this file is created, I want to edit it (add some nodes). This is the code:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "android/data/com.travip/" + activeTrip + ".trp");
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(file);
Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
Element activities = document.createElement("activities");
if (root.getElementsByTagName("activities").getLength() == 0) {
    root.appendChild(activities);
    NodeList activitiesNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("activities");
    activities = (Element) activitiesNodes.item(0);
} else {
    NodeList activitiesNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("activities");
    activities = (Element) activitiesNodes.item(0);
}

Element activity = document.createElement("activity");

activity.setAttribute("name", name);
activity.setAttribute("latLng", latLng);
activity.setAttribute("date", date);
activity.setAttribute("time", time);

activities.appendChild(activity);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

But if the filename of the file (which is was edited) contain a space this space is replaced with %20. So now I have two files, one "name of the trip.trp" without the changes and one "name%20of%20the%20trip.trp" with the changes. How do I write these changes to the same file? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue:
Don't ask me why, but I had to replace

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
```

with

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(file));
```

I sound the soulution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434510/transformer-library-that-comes-with-java-converts-spaces-in-file-paths-to-20)